Android bug with in-app review (play:review) and the keyboard covering the Submit button?
I have a Pixel 8 with Android 14. Not using custom keyboard. I use the in-app reviews API. I noticed the following behavior:


So basically the in-app review component is a bottom sheet. When you try to type a review, the Submit button is covered by the keyboard. There is no easy way to close the keyboard (only the small arrow on the bottom left corner). But a regular user will just try to swipe down the sheet and if you do that... Everything is lost and this panel cannot be re-opened.
Is this a bug in the component? In the specific device? Anybody with a similar experience?

Looks to be expected, from Google feedback:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/361370187#comment4

It is all about Google side dialog UI. we are not interfere in it. even we can't change any UI part from dialog.
You must have to tap back button to close keyboard and then tap submit button.

It seems a horrible choice specially when you have just 1 attempt (every unknown amount of time) to show such native rating dialog.

you can open dialog some number of time , not every time. If the app already has been reviewed by a user, they won't be prompted to review the app again.

That has nothing to do with the question?
